# Position watermark 20px from bottom and bottom left automatically

Tags: automation, photoshop, watermark

I am automating the application of watermarks in photoshop using a batch process. Is there anyway I can position the watermark always  20px from bottom and bottom left regardless of the size of the image the watermark is being placed on?

Currently the watermark is appearing relative to the center (after moving it manually) but because the images are different sizes it never appears bottom right

Comment: I asked the question because obviously you can script in PS, and for all I know the answer to my question could be the application of a script that works out the width and height of the image and applies the watermark absolutely 20px from bottom right

Comment: You might want to ask at the Graphics Stack Exchange as not many users on Stack Overflow are familiar with Photoshop's scripting (only 1.4k questions). As well as this you'll probably get a better answer there.

Answer (score -1):

This can definitely be done through a script - you need to look at the doco for the artLayer.Translate method in the Javascript Ref Guide in your Photoshop installation directory.  I'm not sure if you can do it without scripting.

Use it like this after you've figured out the deltas you need for any given document:

```
var lyr = app.activeDocument.activeLayer;
lyr.translate("-50px","-50px");
```

Comment: That method will shift the layer where he needs it to be - How is that not answering the question?

Comment: ***All of us can see you edited your answer AFTER I commented.*** Your answer, before you edited it, did not answer the question: http://puu.sh/d6FJj/dc22c41bcb.png

Comment: Yes, for the pedantic I added it, but I don't honestly think it adds anything more than was there originally.  Anyone asking questions on this site should be able to work out that very basic code snippet from the original response.